# Combine results from two SQL Server tables even if they don't have common rows

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

Table 1:

```
Silo    Material    F2601 11 This Month
---------------------------------------
1   Bottle Cullet   0
2   Salt Cake   832
2   Sand    0
3   03 Soda Ash 466430
4   Fluorspar   2820
5   Barytes 2393
6   06 Borax    297405
7   Mixed Cullet    12377
8   Syenite 179880
9   09 Bottle Cullet    0
10  10 Sand 1356551
11  11 BD Lime  164171
12  12 EP Dust  13745
13  Fluorspar   14236
14  Bottle Cullet   0
15  Bottle Cullet   0
16  Syenite 0
```

Table 2:

```
Silo    Material    F2601 11 Last Month
---------------------------------------
1   Bottle Cullet   0
2   Sand    0
3   03 Soda Ash 467382
4   Fluorspar   3758
5   Barytes 5028
6   06 Borax    318729
7   Mixed Cullet    20955
8   Syenite 151361
9   09 Bottle Cullet    0
10  10 Sand 1393186
11  11 BD Lime  169514
12  12 EP Dust  11905
13  Fluorspar   0
14  Bottle Cullet   0
14  Bottle Cullet  14   0
15  Bottle Cullet   0
16  Syenite 0
```

and I am looking for a query result of...

```
Silo    Material    F2601 11 This Month F2601 11 Last Month
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Bottle Cullet   0   0
2   Salt Cake   832     0
2   Sand    0   0
3   03 Soda Ash 466430  467382
4   Fluorspar   2820    3758
5   Barytes 2393    5028
6   06 Borax    297405  318729
7   Mixed Cullet    12377   20955
8   Syenite 179880  151361
9   09 Bottle Cullet    0   0
10  10 Sand 1356551 1393186
11  11 BD Lime  164171  169514
12  12 EP Dust  13745   11905
13  Fluorspar   14236   0
14  Bottle Cullet   0   0
14  Bottle Cullet  14   0     0
15  Bottle Cullet   0   0
16  Syenite 0   0
```

Any help is much appreciated. It seems as though I want to combine columns but need columns that exist in one and not the other put into result set with a zero in place for the column that does not exist in that respective table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of well understanding the question. But I'd go with a LEFT JOIN on the IDs, and using IFNULL.

Something like the following query will set you in the right track:

```
SELECT
t1.id, t1.name, t1.number, t2.number
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Then you can play with IFNULL() to better format the results.

Comment: I should mention the opposite scenario could be true. Meaning I could possibly need a right join instead. Not sure if that makes sense. Either table left or right could have data that is not in the other table, but the result set should be the same.

Comment: Seems like a `FULL OUTER JOIN` would be better here. That way you'll get all values from both tables regardless of whether they exist in the other and I think you meant `ISNULL`.